# Using Entity Framework 6 with EntityKey

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to upgrade a big data project from `EF 5` to `EF 6`. But when I run the code generation in `EF6` tool the references to the related tables are no longer there.

So the following line of code no longer works.

```
 dbTradeAllocation.ChargeTypeReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("ICEEntities.SystemData", "ID", TradeAllocation.ChargeType);
```

Does anyone know if `EntityKeys` are still supported in EF6 ?

Thanks Paul

Comment: EntityKey is supported - what code generation are you running? If you are running EF5 code generation then the generated code won't work on EF6 since there were changes in namespaces. It may not be directly related to your code generation but I touched a little bit on this in my blog post http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/ - you need to use EF6 compatible version of code generator.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to use the Entity Object code generator for EF6 [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a).   So my legacy code doesn't break. Paul

Comment: For EF6 you need to use EntityObject generator for EF6. You can get it from here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a (note it requires .NET Framework 4.5 on the dev box)

Comment: Many Thanks. That code generator has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

EntityKey is supported in EF6. However you cannot run EF5 code generation in EF6 - it won't work since there were changes in namespaces. I touched a little bit on this in my blog post about changes to EF Tooling in VS2013 - you can find the blog post [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/). If you want to use EntityObject/ObjectContext entities in EF6 you need to use [EntityObject generator for EF6](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a) which you can get from VS Gallery (note it requires .NET Framework 4.5 on the dev box).

Comment: Your link didn't work. Looked useful so if you could update this comment it would be helpful.

Comment: @JonSmith - I don't know what happened. Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the links.